# Why does the compiler think this variable is undeclared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Employee : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* pin;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString*)name Pin:(NSNumber*)pin;

@end


@implementation Employee

@dynamic name;
@dynamic pin;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString*)iname Pin:(NSNumber*)ipin{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        name = iname;
        pin = ipin; 
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Compiler says name and pin are undeclared in the .m file. What am I doing wrong? 
Putting `self.name` and `self.pin` works, but could someone tell if this is proper or why this works? etc. 
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Proper way to synthesize a property is: @synthesize pin = _pin;

Comment: @zambrey His superclass is `NSManagedObject`.  If `name` and `pin` are entity attributes defined in his Core Data model, he should use `@dynamic`, not `@synthesize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote this in your initializer:

```
name = iname;
```

Since you don't have a local variable named `name`, the compiler looks for an instance variable named `name`, or a static or global variable named `name`.  You don't have an instance variable named `name`, or a static or global either.  You have a property named `name`.  To set the property, you need to either use “dot notation”:

```
self.name = iname;
```

or you need to send a `setName:` message:

```
[self setName:iname];
```

Both of these compile to exactly the same code.

Note that since your superclass is `NSManagedObject`, I assume `Employee` is an entity defined in your Core Data model with attributes `name` and `pin`.  If so, using `@dynamic` is correct.  If those are not attributes defined in your model, you should probably be using `@synthesize` (or omitting both `@dynamic` and `@synthesize` and letting the compiler auto-synthesize the properties).

Comment: Oh i see. I was under the impression that synthesized properties automatically produced the variable. Must've read something incorrectly in my books. Thank you very much rob.

Comment: You're not synthesizing the properties.  You're declaring them dynamic.  Declaring them dynamic is correct if they are entity attributes defined in your Core Data model.  I assume they are entity attributes since your superclass is `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: @ByronS: Note that according to the [NSManagedObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html), managed objects must be initialized using the designated initializer (`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`).